# Sql server 2000 -Space find

Tags: sql-server-2000

This is query:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(datasize varchar(200))

INSERT  #TempTable
   EXEC sp_spaceused 'Table1'
```

When executing this query error message shown as below

> Column name or number of supplied
>   values does not match table definition

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When combining an `insert` and the results of an `execute` you must define the structure of the temp table to be exactly the same number of columns and datatypes as the results of the stored procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a definition mismatch between that temp table and the default output of `sp_spaceused`.

Use:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    objName         varchar(200),
    objRows         varchar(200),
    objReserved     varchar(200),
    objData         varchar(200),
    objIndexSize    varchar(200),
    objUnused       varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
    EXEC sp_spaceused 'Table1'
```